# Exception during teardown in a Transactional DbUnit test

Tags: java, h2, spring-test, dbunit, teardown

Test class declaration

```java
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestH2Config.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DbUnitTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionalTestExecutionListener.class
})
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)
@Transactional
public class BookServiceIT {
    // ... dependencies injection goes here (omitted for brevity)
    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup("/datasets/import.xml")
    public void testCase1() throws Exception {
        // .. create Book in Organization(id=2)
        // ... read and create data in database (omitted for brevity)
    }
}
```

test/resources/datasets/import.xml

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
  <Organization id="2" name="Gov. Library" inactive="false" />
</dataset>
```

Maven command that is used to run tests:

```sh
mvn verify -T 1C
```

I'm attaching an exception stack trace (test fails only in Codeship Linux environment):

```
WARNING: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [com.github.springtestdbunit.TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener@3f191a96] to process 'before' execution of test method [public void com.test.integration.BookServiceIT.testCase1() throws java.lang.Exception] for test instance [com.test.integration.BookServiceIT@15f18e5] org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_JNCMPQJWFCJEXX62EA1P06VLP: ITEST.BOOK FOREIGN KEY(LIBRARY_ID) REFERENCES ITEST.ORGANIZATION(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:delete from ORGANIZATION [23503-195]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:179)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:155)
        at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:425)
        at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRowRefTable(ConstraintReferential.java:442)
        at org.h2.constraint.ConstraintReferential.checkRow(ConstraintReferential.java:317)
        at org.h2.table.Table.fireConstraints(Table.java:976)
        at org.h2.table.Table.fireAfterRow(Table.java:994)
        at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:101)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:101)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:260)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:193)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:165)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingStatement.execute(DelegatingStatement.java:264)
        at org.dbunit.database.statement.SimpleStatement.executeBatch(SimpleStatement.java:69)
        at org.dbunit.operation.DeleteAllOperation.execute(DeleteAllOperation.java:126)
        at org.dbunit.operation.CompositeOperation.execute(CompositeOperation.java:79)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.setupOrTeardown(DbUnitRunner.java:162)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitRunner.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitRunner.java:60)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.DbUnitTestExecutionListener.beforeTestMethod(DbUnitTestExecutionListener.java:160)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.TestExecutionListenerChain$3.call(TestExecutionListenerChain.java:93)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.TestExecutionListenerChain.runChain(TestExecutionListenerChain.java:126)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.TestExecutionListenerChain.forwards(TestExecutionListenerChain.java:115)
        at com.github.springtestdbunit.TestExecutionListenerChain.beforeTestMethod(TestExecutionListenerChain.java:91)
        at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.beforeTestMethod(TestContextManager.java:249)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
        at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
        at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:283)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeWithRerun(JUnit4Provider.java:173)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
```

I've tried to use other execution listeners (that I've found in [DbUnit documentation](https://github.com/springtestdbunit/spring-test-dbunit/#transactions)), but I've got the same exception...

```java
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
```

UPD.: I've tried to add an explicit teardown: deleted the Book in the end of testCase() method. But the exception still persists.

Comment: And what happens if you use a `@DatabaseTearDown` annotation? You're probably right about the implicit deletion, but quite likely, Spring doesn't quite understand your database constraints.

Comment: @SeverityOne I didn't find any good usage examples of this annotation. But while looking I came across a useful attribute of `@DatabaseSetup` (as you can see in the answer below). Thank you for the pushes in the right direction!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

dbUnit deletes the rows in the reverse order of the data listed in the dataset files.  Ensure the files have the rows with foreign keys placed after the ones with the primary keys/one side of the relationship.

Update:
A book table row exists from the test, so tell dbUnit to delete it too.  One way is to add an empty table for the foreign key table to the dataset file **after** the primary table:

```
<book/>
```

So the dbUnit teardown operation sees that table and cleans it up too.

Comment: My dataset import.xml is as simple as it's shown in the question. A book entity is not listed in the dataset; it's created during the test.

Comment: To delete the row, add an entry to the dataset as I wrote in "Update".

Comment: note, that correct empty tag syntax is `<book></book>` or `<book/>`, not `</book>`.

Comment: adding the relation table at the end of the data file works for me. for more information refer to DatabaseOperation.CLEAN_INSERT which clean the mentioned tables in the data file before running the test

Answer (score 0):

It says right there in your stack trace:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Referential integrity constraint violation: "FK_JNCMPQJWFCJEXX62EA1P06VLP: ITEST.BOOK FOREIGN KEY(LIBRARY_ID) REFERENCES ITEST.ORGANIZATION(ID) (2)"; SQL statement:delete from ORGANIZATION [23503-195]
```

So you're deleting from table `ORGANIZATION` when there are still records in the `BOOK` table that refer to the `ORGANIZATION` table via the `FK_JNCMPQJWFCJEXX62EA1P06VLP` foreign key.

Do you have special code to tear down the database? If not, you may need to write it explicitly, or define your foreign key to be `ON DELETE CASCADE` if your business requirements allow that.

Comment: No, I don't have a special code to tear down the database. I believe this delete happens implicitly (managed by Spring Transaction or DbUnit).

Comment: please, see the update: explicit teardown (i.e. book deletion) doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed the behaviour of DbUnit by specifying `type = DatabaseOperation.REFRESH`. Now it doesn't clean the database after test and there's no JDBC exception.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestH2Config.class })
@TestExecutionListeners({
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class,
        DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener.class,
        TransactionDbUnitTestExecutionListener.class
})
@Transactional
public class BookServiceIT {
    // ... dependencies injection goes here (omitted for brevity)
    @Test
    @DatabaseSetup(value = "/datasets/import.xml", type = DatabaseOperation.REFRESH)
    public void testCase1() throws Exception {
        // .. create Book in Organization(id=2)
        // ... read and create data in database (omitted for brevity)
        // .. delete the Book
    }
}
```

See [@DatabaseSetup](https://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/apidocs/com/github/springtestdbunit/annotation/DatabaseSetup.html) documentation.

Comment: This approach leaves the database with results from the test and subsequent tests may have false failures due to it.

Comment: @Jeff, I agree that it doesn't look like a good solution. I just posted it here because it worked for me.